# Vulnerability and patch management on macOS - what works?

Tags: macos, security, auto-update

I am trying to design a plan for patching Mac endpoints at my company.
Are there any readily available tools which I could leverage for continuous security patch/update management for 3rd party apps on Mac. AppFresh seems to be discontinued. I looked into the Sparkle framework. Has anyone used it within an organization, and if yes, what is the best way to use it?

Any thoughts or guidance on operationalizing patch management on macOS in a startup would be highly useful.

Answer (score 1):

For large scale Mac usage in enterprises, you can use [Patch Manager Plus](https://www.manageengine.com/patch-management/?utm_source=Apple_stack)

All the latest security/non-security applications of the OS, as well as third-party applications such as browser updates, Adobe, Java updates, can be patched. Moreover, you can also upgrade from High Sierra to Mojave, apply all the latest supplemental updates with ease. Click here to learn more about [Mac patch management](https://www.manageengine.com/patch-management/mac-patch-management.html?utm_source=Apple_stack) offered by Patch Manager Plus.

Comment: In a comment, please include a statement that you either are, or are not, the developer of this software.